# BeautifulSoup - Internal Server Error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am looping through a few hundred URL's with BeautifulSoup. Recently, a HTTP error has been bugging me. I tried to build a While-loop to repeat the loading of the page until the URL is loaded, but it still shows up. I've gone through the URL's I'm looping manually and there doesn't seem to be any problem with them - the error is also not generated at a certain URL, but rather comes at seemingly random iterations.

[image]

THe code I've tried to solve this with, with no success:

```
    gameCount = 0
    for (index, URL) in enumerate(tempLinkList):

        tryCount = 0
        while tryCount < 500:
            tryCount += 1
            try:
                with urllib.request.urlopen(URL) as url:
                    page = url.read()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")   
            except:
                time.sleep(0.1)
                continue
            else:
                break
```

Any help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: What happen when you access that page via a browser? It could well be that the server just can't handle what you're asking it...

Comment: It works just fine. A specific URL can work just fine in one execution of the code, only to give this error in the next.  So I'm a bit perplexed with how to errorcheck this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status code `500` means

> The **server** encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

This means that, there's nothing wrong with your code. The problem is on the website's side. There's not much you can do about that other than re-sending the request after some time.

In general, the digit in the hundreds' place of the status code has a specific meaning.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes):

- **1xx** - Informational responses
- **2xx** - Success
- **3xx** - Redirection
- **4xx** - Client errors
- **5xx** - Server errors

> Response status codes beginning with the digit "5" indicate cases in which the server is aware that it has encountered an error or is otherwise incapable of performing the request.

Comment: Alright. Is there any way better suited than a while loop for trying to get around this? :)

Comment: How fast are you hitting the server - what is the server? Is it something local that can only handle one things at a time for instance and maybe it hasn't cleared up your old request to handle the new one... Is it just a glitchy unreliable server... etc...? How many URLs do you have - how long do you want to keep trying before giving up - what do you want to do with errors... etc...? It's hard to suggest alternatives when we don't know what you'd like to achieve :)

Comment: 0.1 secs sleep seems too small, did you try a bit larger value? Like 1 or 2 or even 5 secs?

Comment: I'm looping through baseball seasons on ESPN: http://www.espn.com/mlb/schedule/_/date/20060401 (changing the date to every third day, so next date is 20060404)

Comment: @DanielSlätt oh, and before I forget, don't use bare excepts... specifically catch the exception you're after: `except urllib.errors.HTTPError` instead...

Comment: @DanielSlätt you could just use: [`scrapy`](https://scrapy.org/) and let it handle re-queueing requests for failed attempts while it cracks on with others...

Comment: I have to handle them in the right order for this project, but otherwise a good suggestion! It seems that the code liked changing to time.sleep(1) and  specifying the exception - thanks a bunch, guys! :)